# Async calls during authentication logic giving invalid auth

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core, jwt

I've created a program using JWTs and occasionally when a refresh token endpoint is called, the user is hit with a missing token from db error. I have an assumption that my token is deleted before the get token is called, throwing an error.

Inside a dotnet refresh endpoint method, I have:

```
 var refreshTokenDto = await _refreshTokenRepository.GetByToken(reToken);

 if (refreshTokenDto == null)
 {
     return BadRequest(new ErrorResponse("Missing refresh token from db"));
 }

 await _refreshTokenRepository.Delete(refreshTokenDto.Id);
```

Sometimes the users get hit with "Missing refresh token from db".

So for async operations, I'm guessing that the 1st task starts execution then because its async the program continues execution before it finishes. It then starts the 2nd task of deleting, manages to delete the token and then the 1st task finishes and returns null because the token has been deleted.

I think my question is: is my assumption accurate? and how can I prevent it if it is tha case?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you're calling the same method at the same time from multiple threads, you'll want some way of ensuring it can only run once simultaneously for a given token. I use `SemaphoreSlim` for this.

Comment: Your assumptions are wrong. First, the API endpoint will call the `GetByToken` method and wait for the results from DB, and then it will call `Delete` method. However, as @DiplomacyNotWar mentioned, if there are multiple requests came in at the same time to this API endpoint, there will be chance to delete the record from DB by the first request. Besides, take a look whether you have any background job to remove the refresh token from DB after its expiration time.

Comment: Is your repo service scoped or singleton ?

Comment: @Lee I've registered the refresh token repo as a singleton. Would this matter much?